# How can I alter the value in a specific column of a certain row in python without the use of pandas?

Tags: python, csv

I was playing around with the code provided here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/update-column-value-of-csv-in-python/ and couldn't seem to figure out how to change the value in a specific column of the row without it bringing up an error.

Say I wanted to change the status of the row belonging to the name Molly Singh, how would I go about it? I've tried the following below only to get an error and the CSV file turning out empty. I'd also prefer the solution be without the use of pandas tysm.

For example the row in the csv file will originally be
Sno Registration Number   Name              RollNo     Status
1   11913907              Molly Singh       RK19TSA01   P

What I want the outcome to be

Sno Registration Number   Name              RollNo     Status
1   11913907              Molly Singh       RK19TSA01   N

One more question if I were to alter the value in column snow by doing addition/substraction etc how would I go about that as well? Thanks!

[the error I get as you can see, the name column is changed to true then false etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0pJm.png)

```
import csv
  
op = open("AllDetails.csv", "r")
dt = csv.DictReader(op)
print(dt)
up_dt = []
for r in dt:
    print(r)
    row = {'Sno': r['Sno'],
           'Registration Number': r['Registration Number'],
           'Name'== "Molly Singh": r['Name'],
           'RollNo': r['RollNo'],
           'Status': 'P'}
    up_dt.append(row)
print(up_dt)
op.close()
op = open("AllDetails.csv", "w", newline='')
headers = ['Sno', 'Registration Number', 'Name', 'RollNo', 'Status']
data = csv.DictWriter(op, delimiter=',', fieldnames=headers)
data.writerow(dict((heads, heads) for heads in headers))
data.writerows(up_dt)
  
op.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues

1. Your error is because the field name in the input file is misspelled as **Regristation** rather than **Registration**

- Correction is to just read the names from the input file and propagate to the output file as below.
- Alternately, you can your code to:

  headers = ['Sno', 'Regristation Number', 'Name', 'RollNo', 'Status']

2. "One more question if I were to alter the value in column snow by doing addition/substraction etc how would I go about that as well"

- I'm not sure what is meant by this.  In the code below you would just have:

  r['Sno'] = (some compute value)

**Code**

```
import csv
  
with open("AllDetails.csv", "r") as op:
    dt = csv.DictReader(op)
    headers = None
    up_dt = []
    for r in dt:
        # get header of input file
        if headers is None:
            headers = r   
        
        # Change status of 'Molly Singh' record
        if r['Name'] == 'Molly Singh':
            r['Status'] = 'N'
    
        up_dt.append(r)
        
with open("AllDetails.csv", "w", newline='') as op:
    # Use headers from input file above
    data = csv.DictWriter(op, delimiter=',', fieldnames=headers)
    data.writerow(dict((heads, heads) for heads in headers))
    data.writerows(up_dt)
```